# does Apache do any DNS lookups on the Host header

Tags: apache

I have received some results from a security scan that say that something is executing DNS A record look-ups on the URL in the Host header.

Having looked at the application code I can't see any such requests so I'm looking further up the stack.

I don't think Apache should be doing this but it's using mod_headers and mod_rewrite and maybe there is a configuration item in there that I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, I came across an Apache httpd that was configured to do a reverse-lookup for IP-addresses before logging. While this was long denied, some requests were served quickly, while others took a long time (depending on the time required for the reverse lookup). And it became obvious once we looked at the logs (DNS names mixed with IP-addresses)

I don't see any reason why Headers and Rewrite would ever need to resolve any of the domains - they're purely working on strings/regexp.

Recommendation to figure out what's going on: Capture the traffic and figure out what domains/addresses are looked up when. With DNS still being largely unencrypted, this might be fairly easy, and point you to the smoking gun.